# C# MVC Async Partial

Tags: javascript, c#, asynchronous

Difficult Question, we are work with [Async Partial loading](https://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2012/11/13/improve-perceived-performance-of-asp-net-mvc-websites-with-async-partialviews/). After the async part loaded it has some problems to open any modal popups correctly if I do it with a normal @Html.Partial("Example") it works perfectly.

Is there any way to refresh the javascript because of my async loading I think that the async part don't know about my actual javascript.

**Update and solution**

```
function registerPartials() {
    $(".partialContents").each(function (index, item) {
        var url = site.baseUrl + $(item).data("url");
        if (url && url.length > 0) {
            $(item).load(url, function () {
                registerComponents();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

My controller:

```
public partial class AsyncController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Example()
    {
        var vm = new ExampleModel()
        {
            Item = repository.GetContent();
        };
        return PartialView("example", vm);
    }
}
```

My View:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

        <div>
            <div class="partialContents" data-url="/async/example">
                <img src="~/Images/indicator.white.gif" /> Loading ...
            </div>
        </div>

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </div>
    <script language="javascript">
        site.baseUrl = "@Url.Content("~/").TrimEnd('/')";
        $(document).ready(function () {
            register();
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

My partial view:

```
<div>
    <div class="p">blabla</div>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Popup", "Async")" class="dialogbutton">Popup</a>
</div>
```

My Popup class:

```
public ActionResult Popup()
{
    return View("Edit");
}
```

My Popup Edit View:

```
@{
    Layout = IsAjax ? null : "~/Views/Shared/Layout.cshtml";
}
<div class="wrapper"> 
    <h2>Modal Titel</h2>
    <p>This content should be opened in a modal popup.</p>
</div>
```

My Javascript:

```
// Register Partials
function registerPartials() {
$(".partialContents").each(function (index, item) {
    var url = site.baseUrl + $(item).data("url");
    if (url && url.length > 0) {
        $(item).load(url);
    }
});
}

// Creates the dialog boxes
function registerComponents() {
$('.dialogbutton').unbind('click').bind('click', function (e) {
    if (debug) console.log("'.dialogbutton' " + e.type + " event fired");
    e.preventDefault();

    var link = $(this).attr("href") || $(this).data("href");

    //Define Titles & Color
    var dialogtitle = $(this).data("dialog-title");
    var dialogkind = $(this).data("dialog-type");
    var dialogtype = BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DEFAULT;

    //Close Button
    dialogbuttons.push({
        label: 'Schliessen',
        action: function (dialogItself) {
            dialogItself.close();
        }
    });

    //Show BootstrapDialog
    BootstrapDialog.show({
        title: dialogtitle,
        type: dialogtype,
        size: dialogsize,
        //close by clicking on the side
        closeByBackdrop: true,
        //you may want to diable this, but it is awesome
        draggable: true,
        message: function (dialog) {
            var link = dialog.getData('pageToLoad');

            var content = $('<div data-refresh-url="' + link + '">wird geladen...</div>');
            var id = "dialog_0";
            if (activeDialogId != null) {
                var split = activeDialogId.split("_");
                id = "dialog_" + ++split[1];
                content.attr("data-parent-dialog-id", activeDialogId);
            }
            content.attr("id", id);
            activeDialogId = id;

            StartLoadingBar();
            $.ajax({
                url: link,
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    EndLoadingBar();
                    if (data !== false) {
                        var $dialog = $("#" + id);
                        if ($dialog.length > 0) {
                            $dialog.html(data);
                            registerComponents();
                        }
                        else {
                            var waitInterval = setInterval(function () {
                                var $dialog = $("#" + id);
                                if ($dialog.length > 0) {
                                    clearInterval(waitInterval);
                                    $dialog.html(data);
                                    registerComponents();
                                }
                            }, 50);
                        }
                    }
                },
                fail: function (e) {
                    alert(e.status + ': ' + e.statusText + '. Request for ' + link + ' failed');
                    EndLoadingBar();
                }
            });

            return content;
        },
        onhidden: function (dialogRef) {
            var $dialog = $("#" + activeDialogId);
            var parentid = $dialog.data("parent-dialog-id");
            if (parentid != "")
                activeDialogId = parentid;
            else
                activeDialogId = null;

            if (modifiedContentInDialog) {
                if (activeDialogId != null) {
                    var $parentdialog = $("#" + parentid);
                    var link = $parentdialog.data("refresh-url");

                    StartLoadingBar();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: link,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            EndLoadingBar();
                            if (data !== false) {
                                $parentdialog.html(data);
                                registerComponents();
                            }
                        },
                        fail: function (e) {
                            alert(e.status + ': ' + e.statusText + '. Request for ' + link + ' failed');
                            EndLoadingBar();
                        }
                    });

                }
                else {
                    if (reloadAfterSave) {
                        modifiedContentInDialog = false;
                        location.reload();
                    }
                    else {
                        modifiedContentInDialog = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        data: {
            'pageToLoad': link
        },
        buttons: dialogbuttons
    });
});
}
```

My Bundle configuration:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-dialog.js",
                    "~/Scripts/scripts.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/site.css",
                    "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                    "~/Content/bootstrap-dialog.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you're showing appears to be correct, assuming the correct values for `site.baseUrl` and your `data-url` in each of the elements. The problem may be in code you're not including. Hard to say, there isn't enough information here to duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hello I did a Github repo to explain myself there you will see directly what the problem is.
[GithubRepo](https://github.com/twixwix/AsyncPartialExample/tree/master/SampleAsyncPartialViews)
You will find the detail on  AsyncPartialExample/SampleAsyncPartialViews/Views/Async/Index.cshtml

Comment: Any code you're asking about must be included in the question itself. See [mcve] (again)

Comment: I changed my code for better explain my problem. The popup button is not opening in the target popup as it should.

Comment: You've gone just a bit to the opposite extreme. The idea is to be both *complete* and *minimal*. That being said, a suggestion about how to proceed. Open up your browser developer tools. Go to the network tab. Load the page. Look for the XHRs. There should be one per `.partialContents` item. Make sure the url is right, and also look at the results that were returned, and make sure they look as expected. That will tell you whether to look at your server-side code that is sending the partial views, or if you should concentrate on the javascript.

Comment: It looks good for me I've got my html partial response. Still the problem is that my partial know nothing about the function registerComponents and his dialogbutton class. Is there any way to tell the partial view while it is loading that there is some existing scrip? Should I add the registerComponents also in my partialView? `<script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            registerComponents ();
        });
    </script>`

Comment: @David784 Thank you for your help

Comment: @twixwix you're welcome. I'm guessing maybe you already added the `registerComponents` as you asked. Yes that's probably a good idea, the `.load()` callback could easily run before the partial view is fully loaded and ready.